# How to drag cell to another section with a little ImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to drag cell to different sections with a imageView in cell.

Now, I can drag the whole cell to different section or drag a little imageView to current section.

I can't implement both at the same time.

How do you know some good ways to solve it?

Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
>       'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
>       The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) 
>       must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), 
>       plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) 
>       and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 1 moved out).'

```
//移动imageview时执行的操作
func tableView(tableView:UITableView,dragCellFrom fromIndexPath:NSIndexPath,toIndexPath:NSIndexPath){
    print("\(fromIndexPath.section)/n\(fromIndexPath.row)")
    print("\(toIndexPath.section)/n\(toIndexPath.row)")
    let fS = fromIndexPath.section
    let fR = fromIndexPath.row

    let tS = toIndexPath.section
    let tR = toIndexPath.row

    let str = items[fS][fR]

    if tS == 1 && fS == 0{
        let childTaskMap = ModelFactory.childTaskMapOperation().findByProperties("\(rc_ChildTaskMap.ChildID) = \(currentBaby.childID!) and \(rc_ChildTaskMap.IsDeleted) = 'false' and \(rc_ChildTaskMap.TaskID) = \(str.taskID!)")[0]
        childTaskMap.isDeleted = "true"
        ModelFactory.childTaskMapOperation().update(childTaskMap.childTaskMapID!, childTaskMap: childTaskMap)
    }else if tS == 0 && fS == 1{
        let childTaskMap = ModelFactory.childTaskMapOperation().findByProperties("\(rc_ChildTaskMap.ChildID) = \(currentBaby.childID!) and \(rc_ChildTaskMap.IsDeleted) = 'true' and \(rc_ChildTaskMap.TaskID) = \(str.taskID!)")[0]
        childTaskMap.isDeleted = "false"
        ModelFactory.childTaskMapOperation().update(childTaskMap.childTaskMapID!, childTaskMap: childTaskMap)
    }
    items[fS].removeAtIndex(fR)
    items[tS].insert(str, atIndex: tR)
    loadData()
}
```

Comment: Did you update the dataSource correctly?

Comment: ok.I checked my code just now and  found  some problems.Now.I can to drag cell correctly.Thanks for your warning about updating dateSource correctly.

Comment: Now,I have a new problem.I can drag the cell from the  first section to the second section.OK.it is right.But from second section to first section, all cells in second section will be dragged to first section.

Comment: Witouth code, that's hard to tell what's wrong...

Comment: Edit your question, do not put that much code into comment, it's not formatter, harder to read, etc.

Comment: I have put it in question.